# Запрос по двум таблицам

Tags: access

Есть база данных, в ней три таблицы: учёт поступления на склад, учёт выдачи со склада, движение (с уникальными кодами деталей) . Построены таблицы учёта просто: номер накладной, код товара, количество, дата движения.
Как составить запрос, выводящий три столбика: Дата, Количество поступило, Количество выдано
PLease, HELP!!! А то уже голову сломала.. .

Answer (score 1):

вам видимо надо получить данные из объединения 3х таблиц. Для этого используйте

```
   Table1 
   JOIN Table2 ON ...
   JOIN Table3 ON ...
```

После **ON** надо написать условие соединения таблиц - тоесть равенство столбцов.

Comment: нет, это что-то не то((( какие столбцы приравнивать-то?

Comment: Возможно "уникальный код деталей". Только JOIN'ы, вероятно, д.б. внешними (OUTER), возмжно OUTER LEFT JOIN